# Manual switch override for solid-state relay

Tags: circuit-design

I'm using an SSR controlled by an Arduino to control a bulb.  I'd like to wire a manual switch also  in case the Arduino or the SSR isn't working. Basically, it should be OR logic. Either switch or both switches on and the light is on.

I've attached a schematic of circuit.  Will this cause any obvious problems?

[image]

I'm new to schematics, and I should have labeled it line/neutral, not AC/Ground.

The SSR is G3MB-202P.  The datasheet is here: https://www.openhacks.com/uploadsproductos/g3mb-ssr-datasheet.pdf

Comment: What does datasheet for SSR say? Do you have part number?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. What you've named as 'AC source' and 'Ground', are they the mains supply? If so, shouldn't they be 'Line' and 'Neutral'? Ground isn't the return wire for the mains supply.

Comment: The AC source is unconnected on its lower node. AC power wiring does not return to Ground or earth but to neutral.

Comment: You said: "I'm using an SSR controlled by an Arduino to control a bulb." This is not shown in your schematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than the oddly drawn schematic - no problems. If you connect a switch in parallel with the output of your SSR, it will work as you describe.